# editing a rails migration fail after it breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following migration file:

```
class AddDetailsForClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clients, :contact_first_name, :string
    add_column :clients, :contact_last_name, :string
  end
end
```

Problem is there is no previous migration that actual creates the clients table. So when it tries to add a column to nonexistant table, rake db:migrate fails on this migraiton. I am thinking to add this to the same migration file above that line:

```
if !ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('clients')
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to know if there are any better solutions before I try something like that.

Comment: Why do you have a migration with `add_column` to a non-existant table in the first place?

Comment: @Amadan I have no idea how it happened. The migration that created it must have been deleted and it's no longer there. It's not in git. It's not anywhere. So I need a way to create this table before running the other migrations.

Comment: If so, I'd rather just stick `t.string` definitions in `create_table`, instead of `add_column`. But having a change in past migrations might make migrations kind of unusable, as they depend on having a clear shared linear history in order to work as an upgrade mechanism.

Comment: @Amadan so then what's the solution? I'm sure I am not the only one who had this happened to. I want to stick the create table in here, but I also want to make the migrations usable in the future.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. Have you shared your code yet? Is there a deployed app anywhere that you think you would need to migrate? If not, then edit away, change all your migrations as you wish, since you don't have anything that you need to keep compatible to. If there is a migration out there in the deployment land that does create the table and you've lost it, then I'd try really hard to get my paws on it instead rather than rewriting my migration history.

Comment: You can check to see what the current databse is like priorto the migration.  Checkthe file appname/db/schema.  IF the migration hasn't run successfully then use " Create table :clients do |t| .. "